# List Item Varying Height Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see in the screenshot, I have a spacing issue in the first "column". I would like each list item in the same row to have equal heights. It will always be 2 items in each row, so I essentially want to go through every 2 items and set them to the height of the tallest of those items. I've looked through numerous solutions but nothing seems to work for me. I feel like I will need some JS but maybe not.

```
<div id="why-choose-us-list">
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore.</li>
        <li> Magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et.</li>
        <li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>
</div>

#why-choose-us-list {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
}

#why-choose-us-list li {
  background: url(img/bullet.png) left 0 top 3px no-repeat;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 75px;
  padding-top: 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple solution:

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$('#why-choose-us-list li').each(function() {
    maxHeight = $(this).outerHeight() > maxHeight ? $(this).outerHeight() : maxHeight;
});

$('#why-choose-us-list li').height(maxHeight);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/qfocv5om/

Comment: Why DownVote. Please add comments here

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention what browser support is required for your solution but a really nice way to achieve something like this is using flexbox in CSS (browser support is here http://caniuse.com/flexbox and you may need to use vendor prefixes which I haven't but this currently works as is in Chrome). Something like this should do what you want:

```
<style media="screen">
  #why-choose-us-list {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 90%;
  }

  #why-choose-us-list > ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }

  #why-choose-us-list li {
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    width: 48%;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    list-style-image: url(img/bullet.png);
    text-align: left;
  }
</style>
```

I've made a few other changes as well like using list-style-image to display the bullet, there's no need to set it as a background. To do it this way I've switched from using padding-left to margin-left and made sure both are %'s that add up to 50% (or less would work too). I would also suggest using em's for your bottom margin rather than px so that it scales better.

[Working example here](http://jsbin.com/rojojaxupe/1/)

Also worth noting that you had a number of list items all with a width of 50% and padding of another 75px. CSS width does not include padding so each element has 50% + 75px width so those elements can't actually fit 2 per row.

Comment: I wish flexbox was an options at this moment in time for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### Cross-browser compatible solution without the headaches of float

Floats should never be used in layout design. Their purpose is to insert content into a body of text (like an image or an aside) and let the content flow gracefully around it. When misused they can have a lot of issues attached to them, and usually when a page with a float has an issue it is the float.

Flexbox is wonderful, but still not well supported by older browsers.

Instead of floats or flexbox you should use `display: inline-block;` on the items, you will also want to use `vertical-align: top` to fix the alignment issue.

The space between the tags will be rendered as text and therefore will take the space of one character. Use `font-size: 0;` on the parent and `font-size: 1rem` on the items

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/ftzL4z61/1/))

```
#why-choose-us-list {
    font-size: 0px;
}
#why-choose-us-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply clear the third item using css selector.

```
#why-choose-us-list li:nth-child(2n + 1){
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Close to the option I went with

Comment: Yes. but here we can keep any number of items in a row.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this jquery code

```
    var check = true ; 
$('#why-choose-us-list > ul > li').each(function(i){
    if(check == true){
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();
        var NextHeight = $(this).next('li').height();
        if(thisHeight > NextHeight){
            $(this).next('li').css('height',thisHeight+'px');
        }else{
            $(this).css('height',NextHeight+'px');
        }
        $(this).css('background','red');
        $(this).next('li').css('background','yellow');
        check = false;
    }else{
        check = true;
    }
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/9x5xynbq/4/)

Let me explain that

1st : I used `.each()` to loop through (li)s

2nd: I used a boolen check true or false to check the index of li .. I mean if check == true  the code check for li index[0], li index[2], li index[4] ...etc

3rd : I get a outerHeight(true) for

```
li index[0] and next() of it li index[1]
li index[2] and next() of it li index[3] ...
```

4th: made if statement to which of them higher than another .. and then append that height to the smaller li by using .css()

---> Don't forget to include jquery library

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a min-height to styles of these li elements.

```css
#why-choose-us-list {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
}

#why-choose-us-list li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="why-choose-us-list">
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore.</li>
        <li> Magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et.</li>
        <li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not flexible, the text of `li` is varying and can be more to fit in `150px`, this will cause overflow.

Comment: Surely it's better to use a js approach if the height is varying.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I am overwhelmed with the great, quality answers! All of them are options to go with but after messing around with it some more later, I made one simple change. I added:

```
li:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: both;   
}
```

and that fixed it. I'm really only [concerned with IE 8 and above](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child) so this works. It's such a simple fix. I guess that's what I get for trying to work after midnight! Thanks again for all the responses!